# Search inside build events of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way of searching for text inside build events of Visual Studio?
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>f</kbd> doesn't search there even when specifying `Entire Solution`

<sub>(We have dozens of projects in our solution so...)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio won't treat the project *file* as a text file included in the solution, so I fear you're out of luck there.

I'd probably just search through the project files directly, then. I recently hacked together a little PowerShell to get all projects from a solution file:

```
$solution = Get-Content Foo.sln
$projectLines = $solution -match '^Project'
$projects = $projectLines | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^Project.*?=\s*".*?".*?"(.*?)".*$', '$1' } | Where-Object { $_ -match 'proj$' }
```

Applying a `Select-String` after that should be easy, then.

Comment: Since I have never used the PowerShell the `Select-String` is not easy ... can't you show me an example for searching "foo"?

Comment: Assuming above code snippet: `Select-String foo $projects` should work.